# The plot doesn't appear in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I was following a tutorial to learn data analysis to plot a graph and here is my code

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv("avocado.csv")
df["Date"]=pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])
albany_df=df[df["region"]=="Albany"]
albany_df.set_index("Date",inplace=True)
albany_df["AveragePrice"].plot()
```

there is no bugs with the code as **there is no error massages **
only this line appear (with no graph)

```
<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0x2556f2158d0>
```

Comment: `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` and at the end of the code `plt.show()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to import matplotlib, and do a show() :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_csv("avocado.csv")
df["Date"]=pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])
albany_df=df[df["region"]=="Albany"]
albany_df.set_index("Date",inplace=True)
albany_df["AveragePrice"].plot()
plt.show()
```

Comment: In the tutorial the instructor did not use matplot    https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DamIIzp41Jg&list=PLQVvvaa0QuDfSfqQuee6K8opKtZsh7sA9&index=2

Comment: He is using jupyter notebook. With the magic commande %matplotlib  inline. May e he skipped thé explain action, but he is well using matplotlib